# How to show the alert box on every page load in the application using $routeProvider in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, alert, route-provider

i'm  working on Angularjs .

My challenge for the day is to display  the alert box in all the page load .

Whenever the page is redirecting I need to  get  an  alert box with some message. I know it  is easy  to  use alert in all the places of redirecting .But what  i'm looking for is to use the alert only once which effects on entire application . So whenever the page redirect happens I need to  get an alert box . Please help me out of this .

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: "loginCtrl",
        templateUrl: "views/account/login.html",
        label: "Home",


        resolve: {
          initialised: function () {

            alert("Hi");
          }}


    }),
    $routeProvider.when('/account/login', {
        controller: "loginCtrl",
        templateUrl: "views/account/login.html",
        label: "Login Page"
    })
```

Comment: use $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function () {                
             alert("Hi");
        });

also you can use 
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {
           alert("Hi");
        });

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with handling `$locationChangeStart` event

```
angular.module('app')
      .controller(
        'MyRootController',
        function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $log) {
          $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
            //You can write your alert box logic here 
            $log.info("location changing to:" + next); 
          });
        }
      );
```

Comment: thank you  for your answer , I have another doubt whether to use this in  controller or in  my  app.js page

Comment: You can use it in main controller.